# Full Calendar renders the wrong end date

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

FullCalendar renders the end date incorrectly, end date goes to next date...
Even if theres no 'end'..
See screenshots below

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue.. after I changed to 12hour format